# How to Sort Geo-points according to the distance from current location in Android

Tags: android, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have a "Place" object with a LatLng coordinate for each:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class Place{
    public String name;
    public LatLng latlng;

    public Restaurant(String name, LatLng latlng) {
        this.name = name;
        this.latlng = latlng;
    }
}
```

and I have an ArrayList of these Places, something like this:

```
    ArrayList<Place> places = new ArrayList<Place>();
    places.add("Place 1", LatLng(90.0,90.0));
    places.add("Place 2", LatLng(93.0,93.0));
    places.add("Place 3", LatLng(83.0,92.0));
    places.add("Place 4", LatLng(93.0,91.0));
```

and I have "my" LatLng:

```
    LatLng myLocation = new LatLng(10.0,10.0);
```

How can I sort these objects according to closest to me? Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you familiar with the Comparable interface?

Comment: I am, I've used it for simple things like comparing ints, however  I'm not sure how to compare something like distance - which needs to be calculated first

Comment: This should be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396286/sort-list-of-lon-lat-points-start-with-nearest

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Taking the algorithm from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396286/sort-list-of-lon-lat-points-start-with-nearest/5396425#5396425) from the question posted by @shieldstroy, that uses the [Great Circle Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance), I got this example working.

Here is the `Comparator`:

```
public class SortPlaces implements Comparator<Place> {
    LatLng currentLoc;

    public SortPlaces(LatLng current){
        currentLoc = current;
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(final Place place1, final Place place2) {
        double lat1 = place1.latlng.latitude;
        double lon1 = place1.latlng.longitude;
        double lat2 = place2.latlng.latitude;
        double lon2 = place2.latlng.longitude;

        double distanceToPlace1 = distance(currentLoc.latitude, currentLoc.longitude, lat1, lon1);
        double distanceToPlace2 = distance(currentLoc.latitude, currentLoc.longitude, lat2, lon2);
        return (int) (distanceToPlace1 - distanceToPlace2);
    }

    public double distance(double fromLat, double fromLon, double toLat, double toLon) {
        double radius = 6378137;   // approximate Earth radius, *in meters*
        double deltaLat = toLat - fromLat;
        double deltaLon = toLon - fromLon;
        double angle = 2 * Math.asin( Math.sqrt(
                Math.pow(Math.sin(deltaLat/2), 2) +
                        Math.cos(fromLat) * Math.cos(toLat) *
                                Math.pow(Math.sin(deltaLon/2), 2) ) );
        return radius * angle;
    }
}
```

Here is the high level code, I just put this in `onCreate()`:

```
        //My location, San Francisco
        double lat = 37.77657;
        double lng = -122.417506;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

        //set up list
        ArrayList<Place> places = new ArrayList<Place>();

        places.add(new Place("New York", new LatLng(40.571256,73.98369)));
        places.add(new Place("Colorado", new LatLng(39.260658,-105.101615)));
        places.add(new Place("Los Angeles", new LatLng(33.986816,118.473819)));

        for (Place p: places){
            Log.i("Places before sorting", "Place: " + p.name);
        }

        //sort the list, give the Comparator the current location
        Collections.sort(places, new SortPlaces(latLng));

        for (Place p: places){
            Log.i("Places after sorting", "Place: " + p.name);
        }
```

Here is the log output:

```
04-17 23:04:16.074  12963-12963/com.maptest.daniel.maptest I/Places before sorting﹕ Place: New York
04-17 23:04:16.074  12963-12963/com.maptest.daniel.maptest I/Places before sorting﹕ Place: Colorado
04-17 23:04:16.074  12963-12963/com.maptest.daniel.maptest I/Places before sorting﹕ Place: Los Angeles
04-17 23:04:16.074  12963-12963/com.maptest.daniel.maptest I/Places after sorting﹕ Place: Los Angeles
04-17 23:04:16.074  12963-12963/com.maptest.daniel.maptest I/Places after sorting﹕ Place: Colorado
04-17 23:04:16.074  12963-12963/com.maptest.daniel.maptest I/Places after sorting﹕ Place: New York
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ended up doing this

Comment: What if you have like 10k locations to calculate and sort them by distance?

Comment: @Beemo use Google Play Services and the distanceBetween or distanceTo function in a comparator for the best efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

For calculating the distance there are different methods available. A quite simple one is the Haversine Formula (http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#Java). A more accurate calculation would be the Vincenty Formula. If the two locations are not far away, the Haversine solution is quite sufficient.

After calculating the distance, you just sort your array using a comparator, like:

```java
Collections.sort(places, new Comparator<Place>() {
    public int compare(Place p1, Place p2) {
        return Double.compare(p1.getDistance(), p2.getDistance());
    }
});
```

Comment: What if you have like 10k locations to calculate and sort them by distance?

Comment: @Beemo use Google Play Services and the distanceBetween or distanceTo function in a comparator for the best efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

As you got your current location, You can sort by calculating the driving distance (which is most suitable for places like restaurants ) as follows,

1. Calculate the distance to each object

   ```
   http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+yourLat+","+yourLong+"&destination="+toLat+","+toLong+"&sensor=false&mode=DRIVING
   ```
2. Once you calculate each distance , apply some simple sorting algorithm for those distances.

Comment: Do you happen to know if the google maps API gets distance by road route or by straight line?

Comment: i think it provides road route not straight line

Comment: I'll check it out, if it is route directions, it will def be more useful than straight line, thanks again

Comment: welcome , definitely you need road route as straight distance just provide the difference between two Geo points which is no usable in real world.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the

```
distanceInMeters = (loc1.distanceTo(loc2));
```

from google maps API and then add the results to the Key in a TreeMap